# Efficiently solving $9\,\_\,8\,\_\,7\,\_\,6\,\_\,5\,\_\,4=2020$ (filling blanks with $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, and using parentheses)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Our physics teacher gives us problems every week to solve for fun. This week, we got this:

> $$9\,\_\,8\,\_\,7\,\_\,6\,\_\,5\,\_\,4=2020$$
>   Fill in the blanks with the operations $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$. Parentheses can be used as you wish.

Despite my attempts at trying to find an elegant way to solve this problem, I eventually gave up and tried brute forcing an answer along with a friend, attempting to try out all of the $4^5×5!$ (I think) possibilities, along with some very basic high-level strategies for some filtering.

A classmate, who used something like a brute force approach and happened to be lucky enough to stumble upon the right answer early got this:

> $$(9 \times 8 \times 7 + 6 - 5) \times 4 = 2020$$

While we have an answer, I would like to know if there's a better approach - one that's more elegant and/or efficient.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The puzzle could have continued with "$\_3\_2\_1$". I wonder if this was avoided in order to make the solution unique.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to + and -, then this becomes the subset sum problem which is not known to have an efficient solution.  I'm not sure right now how the other operators and parenthesis affect the problem.

Comment: You clearly need at least two, and probably three, multiplications to get the result large enough. Equally you should (fairly) clearly avoid division. So there are not that many cases to consider.

Comment: @almagest Right, these were the exact 'high-level strategies' I was referring to. Looking back, it did help filter a lot, not just a 'little bit'. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @AdityaRadhakrishnan You might also edit your answer. The minus sign is in the wrong place.

Comment: @almagest Ah, yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that there are a lot of approaches to this problem, but i would consider the following:

Obviously 2020 is too large to be the result of some calculation which does not use a multiplication. So we need $\times$ at least once. That is why one should take a look at the prime factorization of 2020 which leads to
$$2020 = 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 101.$$
This is why i would decide to choose a $\times$ before the 4. Now we have 505 left which is quite large. So i started to multiply the numbers from left to right which leads to
$$9 \times 8 \times 7 = 504.$$
This is luckily quite close to 505 which we are looking for and can then be received by adding 6 und subtracting 5. This finally leads us to
$$(9 \times 8 \times 7 + 6 - 5) \times 4 = 2020.$$
However, there might be even more efficient ways to that. In particular, concerning the last steps when it comes to figuring out how to receive 505.

Comment: Well, my friend and I used a pretty similar strategy and we got 505. We were almost done, but by then our classmate figured it out.

Comment: I don't think you can always try putting the × before the 4, because it could also be such that you use the other numbers to get 2024, for example, then _subtract_ 4, or use the other numbers excluding 5 to get 2021, and subtract 5 - 4, which is 1, or many other things - or is it that I'm missing something?

Comment: You are totally right @aravk33 and that is exactly what i wanted to point out: There is no guarantee that this approach works. But it is a more strategic approach than just using brute force and that was what i focused on.